# How to get specific image alt text from WordPress media library?

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I have a bunch of images stored in my WordPress media library. Each of these has an alt text assigned to it by using the WordPress UI, as follows:

[image]

I am trying to get the image alt text from within my php template files. How exactly can i do this?

I know i can get the URL using the `get_template_directory_uri()` method

```
<img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/path/to/logo/logo.png">
```

But how can i specifically get the alt text of the image in the media library?

Comment: get_post_meta( 'your image id here', '_wp_attachment_image_alt', true);

Comment: Thanks. How can i find out the image ID?

Comment: go to the wp-admin->media->required image->edit it, in url you will find a post id, that is your image id

Comment: Is there a way to get the image alt text without the image id? Maybe by image name?

Comment: then you need to write a custom function

Comment: Ok. Thanks a lot for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

I have written a function to do exactly that.

Add this function to your **functions.php**.

```
function image_alt_by_url($image_url) {
$image_id   = attachment_url_to_postid($image_url);
$alt = get_post_meta($image_id, '_wp_attachment_image_alt', true);
return $alt; 
}
```

In you template, call this function with the image url as parameter value.

```
echo image_alt_by_url( get_template_directory_uri().'/path/to/logo/logo.png' );
```