# How do I add alt tags to images in the Wordpress theme file?

Tags: wordpress

I have the following code that inserts an image spinner while a woocommerce product information loads. However, it doesn't pick up the alt tags for the images. Does anyone know how to grab that information from the media file?

```
    // Insert the spinner HTML
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_websiteexample_product_loader', 60 );

if ( ! function_exists( 'woocommerce_websiteexample_product_loader' ) ) {

    function woocommerce_websiteexample_product_loader() {
        $base_url = "/wp-content/themes/websiteexample/assets/images/";
        $image_list = array(
            "image1.png",
            "image2.png",
            "image3.png",
            "image4.png"
        );

        // wc_get_template( 'single-product/share.php' );
        echo "<div class='deal-loader-container'>";
            echo "<div class='table full'>";
                echo "<div class='table-cell vertical-align'>";
                    echo "<div class='relative'>";
                        echo "<h2>Please wait...</h2>";
                        echo "<div class='deal-loader'></div>";

                        foreach ($image_list as $image) 
                        {
                            echo "<img src='" . $base_url . $image . "'>";
                        }
                    echo "</div>";
                echo "</div>";
            echo "</div>";
        echo "</div>";
    }
}
```

Comment: You are looking for the alt tags in the image file?

Comment: Hey @HowardE, in the media section of the wordpress backend these image files have the alt tag already set. So I was hoping the function in the them would be able to grab that.

Comment: Like this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51554589/how-to-get-specific-image-alt-text-from-wordpress-media-library

Comment: @HowardE yes, I believe so! I'm terrible at php so I'll try figure out how to implement it. Thank you :)